# Getting SyntaxError: Empty JSON string in Mirth Connect while sending an empty Message

Tags: javascript, json, mirth

**ERROR Which I received while sending Message**

**I Want to Resolve this Can anyone help me to Resolve this Error who is expert in Mirth**

**[Error Message**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YkVs.png) 
[If you  seeing this img in status tab i'm getting error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rupC8.png)

Expectation

I want sent message there in Status message tab

[ERROR MESSAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQjjv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Using JSON as the inbound type on your transformer expects that you will be getting valid JSON data (which an empty string is not.) If there is a possibility that you will receive malformed data, and you do not want it to error, then you will need to handle that data yourself, and likely use a source filter to stop the messages from processing further.

One possible solution to blank messages is to use the pre-processor script for the channel, which processes the message as a plain string before it goes into the transformer. In your pre-processor you can do:

```js
if (message === '') {
    message = '{"filterInMirth": true}'
}
return message
```

Changing the message to valid JSON will allow it to process in the filter and transformer without causing an error. Then in your source filter you can pass only messages where the `filterInMirth` property is not true.